# FullPage.js: Only show navigation when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm making a website with fullPage.js and for design purposes I want the navigation only to show when scrolling. I've tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                //navigation
                menu: '#menu',             
                navigation: window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){return true}),
                navigationPosition: 'right',
                scrollBar: true,
            }); 
        });
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Er, `addEventListener` takes a *function*.

Comment: navigation: window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){return true}) like this? Thanks but still no luck, I'll update my question

Comment: Adding to gcampbell, fullPage.js comes with beforeMove and afterMove methods, so you can use like beforeMove:function(){nav.style.display = '';}, afterMove:function(nav.style.display = 'none'}

Comment: fullpage.js doesn't have a feature for  "show navigation on scroll" so you'll have to write it yourself. Maybe something like `var nav = document.querySelector('nav'); nav.style.display = 'none'; document.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(function () { nav.style.display = '' }, 250));`. Assuming that the navigation is a `<nav>` element. Also assumes lodash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on help from @gcampbell this worked for me

```
var nav = document.querySelector('#fp-nav'); 
        nav.style.display = 'none'; 
        document.addEventListener('scroll', function () { 
            nav.style.display = 'inline';
            setTimeout(function(){ nav.style.display = 'none'}, 1000); 
        });
    });
```